# Relay and Apollo,which one is easier?

Tags: react-native

I want to write an app with `React Native`,front end has two choices:

1、Relay + React Native
2、Apollo + React Native

Which one is easier? And I don't want to use `redux`.

Comment: Depends mostly on what&amp;#39;s using your api server. None of them are 'easy' and both can be used without redux

Comment: @Dyo `Apollo` manages application's state with `apollo-link-state`,what about `Relay`?